# Get document set path in sharepoint using javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

On sharepoint online, I have a document (id=123). The document is in a document set using javascript. When I try and find the path for that document set I get an error.

The code I have is:

```
var item;
var folder;

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(editLinks, "sp.js");

function editLinks()
{
     getItemParent(123);
}

function getItemParent(itemID)
{
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(); 

    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    var targetList = web.get_lists().getByTitle([List Name]);
    item = targetList.getItemById(itemID);
    clientContext.load(item, 'DisplayName');
    clientContext.load(item, 'Folder');
    folder = item.get_folder();
    clientContext.load(folder);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {   
    console.log(item.get_displayName());
    console.log(folder.get_serverRelativeUrl());
}

function onQueryFailed() {   
    console.log("Query Failed");
}
```

When I run it the item.get_displayName() works fine, but it throws the following error when trying to get serverRelativeUrl:

```
sp.runtime.js:2 Uncaught Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object on server. The object is associated with property Folder.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my test script for your reference.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var item;
        //var folder;

        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(editLinks, "sp.js");

        function editLinks() {
            getItemParent(6);
        }

        function getItemParent(itemID) {
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();

            var web = clientContext.get_web();
            var targetList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("LibDS");
            item = targetList.getItemById(itemID);
            //folder = item.get_folder();
            clientContext.load(item);
            //clientContext.load(item, 'DisplayName');
            //clientContext.load(item, 'Folder');            
            //clientContext.load(folder);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
                Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

        }

        function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
            console.log(item.get_fieldValues("FileDirRef").FileDirRef);
            //console.log(folder.get_serverRelativeUrl());
        }

        function onQueryFailed() {
            console.log("Query Failed");
        }
    </script>
```

[image]